# Регистрация в VK через API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Добрый день. 
Неоднократно натыкался в интернете на программы которые позволяют регистрировать аккаунты для вк в автоматическом режиме.

Возник интерес написать что-то похожее для себя. И сразу же столкнулся с первой проблемой. В официальном API я не нашел методов через которые можно осуществить регистрацию.

Возникает вопрос, как другие это делают? 
Буду благодарен за любой ответ!

Comment: путаете, регистрация на внешнем сайте с помощью авторизации в вк, нет сейчас автоматической регистрации в вк, 1 телефон = 1 пользователь.

Comment: Я понимаю, что 1 телефон = 1 пользователь. Мне просто интересно, как они на программном уровне отправляют запрос в вк для регистрации

Comment: регистрации чего? регистрации человека нет по api.

Comment: а как тогда работает BotReg?

Comment: видимо curl и тому подобными фишками.

Comment: Всё что они пишут на странице API то и используйте. Если чего-то нет, значит доступа вам не получить к таким действиям. Можете без API подключаться к серверу и задать логику регистрации с использованием таймаутов.

Answer (score 1):

В автоматическом режиме регистрация в VK сейчас невозможна. Требуется подтверждение по номеру телефона и обязательный секретный ключ приложения при использовании методов регистрации `auth.signup` и `auth.confirm`. Кроме того, даже при переборе различных номеров есть количественные и частотные ограничения на регистрацию (накладываются по IP-адресу и ID приложения).

Что касается "программ автоматической регистрации", то в большинстве случаев они делают что угодно, кроме самой регистрации. Самые честные используют вышеуказанные методы и просто немного снижают количество рутинных процессов при регистрации по телефонному номеру.